# How should timeouts be aligned when connecting to API gateway and lambas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I have a gateway which makes a request to API gateway that has a lambda behind it.

The gateway has a timeout of 5s, and the lambda has a timeout of 4s. Is this correct way of always aligning the timeouts from top down?

Comment: Depends, there is no golden rule. There can be arguments for the lambda to have 15 minutes timeout even if the api gateway has the 29s timeout. But there are also arguments for the lambda timeout to be equal to (or slightly less than) the gateway timeout.

Comment: Hmm but if your gateway is shorter than your lambda and your lambda takes longer, your gateway will then timeout and you won't know exactly what in the lambda took long?

Comment: Yes. But in may be that you do not want the lambda to timeout even if the gateway timed out because you cannot risk the lambda stopping work halfway through. And you won't know what took long regardless of the timeout, you need logging and debugging to figure that out.